# Ventana "Just-In-Time debugger" después de instalar FileZilla

Tags: ftp

Buenas noches con todos. Quisiera que me explicaran por favor que significa o a que se debe este mensaje. Surgió después de haber instalado y ejecutado FailZilla. Tampoco entiendo por que el mensaje proviene del Visual Studio que lo instalé hace unas semanas. Cualquier sugerencia estaré agradecido. (Nota: El FileZilla está funcionando correctamente, mi SO es win 8.1 64bits)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No es posible darte una respuesta exacta de porqué te está ocurriendo esto, pero intentaremos ayudar.

Primero, el aviso te proviene del Visual Studio porque al instalar algunos entornos de desarrollo también se instala un depurador/debugger que recoge los fallos de las aplicaciones y te permite depurarlas para intentar ver cual ha sido el error. Esto es útil cuando estás desarrollando algún código al que no le puedes hacer una depuración normal (como puede ser una dll que interactúa con otras aplicaciones o con el sistema, por ejemplo).

En este caso en particular, el depurador detecta que ha ocurrido un error en el proceso "Lavasoft.WCAssistant.Winservice.exe" y te da la opción de depurarlo... aunque no tengas el código ni lo hayas desarrollado tu.

Esto nos lleva a la causa del mensaje. Lavasoft es una casa de desarrollo de firewall, antivirus y antimalware. Probablemente tengas instalado algún producto de este desarrollador, y al instalar filezilla se haya sobrescrito algún fichero del firewall/antivirus/antimalware (probablemente alguna dll que usen ambos programas tenga el mismo nombre), o quizás haya alguna interacción entre ambas aplicaciones que hace fallar al producto de Lavasoft.

Quizás la solución más práctica sea que reinstales ambas aplicaciones (filezilla y la de lavasoft), a ver si así logras restaurar los archivos de ambas aplicaciones. Si aún así sigue fallando, probablemente sea alguna incompatibilidad entre ambas aplicaciones y tendrás que ver si hay alguna actualización que corrija este fallo, o cambiar alguna de las aplicaciones por otra que haga el mismo trabajo.